# Why this is generating error, where is the problem?

Tags: r, h2o

```
Rfmodel<-h2o.grid("randomForest",
              search_criteria = list(
                strategy="RamdomDiscrete",
                stopping_metric ="mse",
                stopping_tolerance= 0.001,
                stopping_rounds=5,
                max_runtime_secs=240
              ),
              hyper_params = list(
                ntrees=c(50,100,200,250),
                mtries=c(1,2,4,6),
                sample_rate=c(0.3,0.5,0.75,0.90),
                col_sample_rate_per_tree=c(0.25,0.50,0.75,0.1)
              ),
              x=8,y=1:7,training_frame = data.train,nfolds=4,max_depth=50,
              stopping_metric="misclassification",
              stopping_tolerance=0,
              stopping_rounds=5,
              seed=2
              )
```

Error in .h2o.doSafeREST(h2oRestApiVersion = h2oRestApiVersion, urlSuffix = page,  :

ERROR MESSAGE:

Can't parse the search_criteria dictionary; got error: search_criteria.strategy for raw value: {"strategy"="RamdomDiscrete","stopping_metric"="misclassification","stopping_tolerance"=0.001,"stopping_rounds"=5,"max_runtime_secs"=240}

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: I'm not sure what _your_ problem is because _our_ problem is that we don't have your training data frame, `data.train`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, It is running now, I don't know how but I run after restart my PC.